How to reject incoming requests in Rocket using a Fairing?
I'm trying to check if the user has sent a cookie using a Fairing, but I'm not able to find a solution to reject the incoming request by blocking it.
#[rocket::async_trait]
impl Fairing for LoginCheck {
    fn info(&self) -> Info {
        Info {
            name: "Login Check",
            kind: Kind::Request | Kind::Response,
        }
    }

    async fn on_request(&self, request: &mut Request<'_>, _: &mut Data<'_>) {
        let auth_cookie = request.cookies().get("auth")
        // block the request here
    }

    async fn on_response<'r>(&self, _request: &'r Request<'_>, response: &mut Response<'r>) {
        response.set_header(Cookie::new("auth", "test cookie"));
    }
}

I want to know a way to block the request or if there is any other way to solve the problem in which the route handlers need not have to check if the user has sent the cookie.

Found a similar question with solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70011965/global-authentication-authorization-in-rocket-based-on-a-header?rq=2

You can't short-circuit the request-response flow with a Fairing. The documentation says:

A request callback is called just after a request is received. A request callback can modify the request at will and peek into the incoming data. It may not, however, abort or respond directly to the request; these issues are better handled via request guards or via response callbacks.

And for authentication in particular:

Warning
[..] You should not use a fairing to implement authentication or authorization unless the authentication or authorization applies to all or the overwhelming majority of the application.

And even then, you can only somewhat implement authentication in a fairing; you can do token-validation, user-lookups, and permission checks. But to actually act on that information requires logic in the handler or probably better a request guard that reads what was stored in the request-local cache by your authentication fairing.
